# APT encountered a lot of errors

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and recently adjusted my firewall so that citadel groupware could work properly, but after I got it setup and configured, I did the command `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but it seems to fail. So I thought maybe the server is down and I went on to install the suggested anti-virus and spam blocker but I got the same lines of code which are as following:

```
root@pe-fw:/etc# apt-get install spamassassin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-xapian-index aptitude-common gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.9-base libapt-inst1.5 libarchive-extract-perl libbind9-90 libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libboost-iostreams1.58.0 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libck-connector0 libclass-accessor-perl
  libcwidget3 libdns100 libept1.4.12 libfcgi-perl libgck-1-0 libgcr-3-common libgcr-base-3-1 libio-string-perl libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libjson0 liblog-message-perl liblog-message-simple-perl liblwres90 libmodule-pluggable-perl
  libmodule-runtime-perl libparams-classify-perl libparse-debianchangelog-perl libpod-latex-perl libprocps3 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libsub-name-perl libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libterm-ui-perl libtext-soundex-perl libxapian-1.3-5
  libxapian22v5 libxtables10 linux-headers-3.13.0-142 linux-headers-3.13.0-142-generic linux-image-3.13.0-142-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-142-generic python-ndg-httpsclient python-requests python-urllib3 python-xapian
  python3-xapian1.3
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdigest-hmac-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libmail-spf-perl libnet-dns-perl libnet-ip-perl libnetaddr-ip-perl libsocket6-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl re2c sa-compile spamc
Suggested packages:
  razor libio-socket-ssl-perl libdbi-perl pyzor libmail-dkim-perl libencode-detect-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdigest-hmac-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libmail-spf-perl libnet-dns-perl libnet-ip-perl libnetaddr-ip-perl libsocket6-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl re2c sa-compile spamassassin spamc
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,963 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,533 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
et:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libdigest-hmac- 
perl all 1.03+dfsg-1 [12.1 kB]
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libsocket6-perl 
i386 0.25-1build2 [23.9 kB]
Get:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libio-socket- 
inet6-perl all 2.72-2 [13.8 kB]
Get:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libnet-ip-perl 
all 1.26-1 [31.5 kB]
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libnet-dns-perl 
i386 0.81-2build1 [266 kB]
Get:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libnetaddr-ip- 
perl i386 4.078+dfsg-1build1 [82.6 kB]
Get:7 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libmail-spf-perl 
all 2.9.0-4 [115 kB]
Get:8 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libsys-hostname- 
long-perl all 1.5-1 [11.7 kB]
Get:9 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 re2c i386 0.16-1         
[225 kB]
Get:10 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 spamassassin all 
3.4.1-3 [1,116 kB]
Get:11 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 sa-compile all 
3.4.1-3 [13.8 kB]
Get:12 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 spamc i386 
3.4.1-3 
[52.2 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package libdigest-hmac-perl.
(Reading database ... 166167 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdigest-hmac-perl_1.03+dfsg-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdigest-hmac-perl (1.03+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsocket6-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libsocket6-perl_0.25-1build2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libsocket6-perl (0.25-1build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libio-socket-inet6-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libio-socket-inet6-perl_2.72-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libio-socket-inet6-perl (2.72-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnet-ip-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libnet-ip-perl_1.26-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnet-ip-perl (1.26-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnet-dns-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libnet-dns-perl_0.81-2build1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnet-dns-perl (0.81-2build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnetaddr-ip-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libnetaddr-ip-perl_4.078+dfsg-1build1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnetaddr-ip-perl (4.078+dfsg-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmail-spf-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmail-spf-perl_2.9.0-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmail-spf-perl (2.9.0-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsys-hostname-long-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libsys-hostname-long-perl_1.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsys-hostname-long-perl (1.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package re2c.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/re2c_0.16-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking re2c (0.16-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package spamassassin.
Preparing to unpack .../spamassassin_3.4.1-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking spamassassin (3.4.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package sa-compile.
Preparing to unpack .../sa-compile_3.4.1-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking sa-compile (3.4.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package spamc.
Preparing to unpack .../spamc_3.4.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking spamc (3.4.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up ifupdown (0.8.10ubuntu1.3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K15webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service webcit and plymouth if started
insserv:  loop involving service plymouth at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service webcit at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service rsyslog at depth 1
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ifupdown (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up clamav-freshclam (0.99.4+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K15webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service webcit and plymouth if started
insserv:  loop involving service plymouth at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service webcit at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service rsyslog at depth 1
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package clamav-freshclam (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamav:
 clamav depends on clamav-freshclam (>= 0.99.4+addedllvm) | clamav-data; however:
  Package clamav-freshclam is not configured yet.
  Package clamav-data is not installed.
  Package clamav-freshclam which provides clamav-data is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package clamav (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libdigest-hmac-perl (1.03+dfsg-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up libsocket6-perl (0.25-1build2) ...
Setting up libio-socket-inet6-perl (2.72-2) ...
Setting up libnet-ip-perl (1.26-1) ...
Setting up libnet-dns-perl (0.81-2build1) ...
Setting up libnetaddr-ip-perl (4.078+dfsg-1build1) ...
Setting up libmail-spf-perl (2.9.0-4) ...
Setting up libsys-hostname-long-perl (1.5-1) ...
Setting up re2c (0.16-1) ...
Setting up spamassassin (3.4.1-3) ...
Adding system user `debian-spamd' (UID 116) ...
Adding new group `debian-spamd' (GID 123) ...
Adding new user `debian-spamd' (UID 116) with group `debian-spamd' ...
Creating home directory `/var/lib/spamassassin' ...
insserv: warning: script 'K15webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service webcit and plymouth if started
insserv:  loop involving service plymouth at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service webcit at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service rsyslog at depth 1
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package spamassassin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sa-compile:
 sa-compile depends on spamassassin; however:
  Package spamassassin is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package sa-compile (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up spamc (3.4.1-3) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ifupdown
 clamav-freshclam
 clamav
 spamassassin
 sa-compile
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

update: i noticed something in the lines of code that i found odd as i tried to remove citadel, thinking that might be the cause, i noticed a few words that correlated to citadel and after some research and trail and error it seemed to be that citadel wasn't compleetly gone yet so i am trying to track down the remaining parts of it and try to remove them to see what will happen

Comment: Please edit your question and copy the error message as text into the question.

Comment: @Bruni would love to but the link clearly says what is going to happen if i do that, is seen as spam as the error repeats several things i itself

Comment: @Melebius so if i am getting this right you are saying the link i provided isn't working? or am i missing the point here?

Comment: @Melebius okay didn't know it did that and i will try and put the lines of code in there, if it wants to work that is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I noticed some file names which correlated to citadel. I looked these up and removed them. After that I rebooted the machine, ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and now the ubuntu working fine again

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to assume this problem is related to citadel.  From what I can see, everything within 'apt' is functioning properly, and it's warning you that the citadel installation has issues.

My recommendations:

```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt remove spamassassin citadel-suite citadel-webcit
    sudo apt autoclean
    sudo apt autoremove
    sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

The above five commands should remove spamassassin and citadel, then clean up unneeded packages, and finally update the existing software on your machine.

Once this is done, let us know if you see any errors from 'apt'.

As long as everything is clean after the above, you can reinstall citadel, checking to see if there are any issues after installation.

Once you know citadel installed without issue, you can then reinstall spamassassin.

Good luck.